# Split a string in column and count occurrence of characters

Tags: r

I have a very huge file with dim: 47,685 x 10,541. In that file, there is no spaces between the characters in each row in the second column, as following:

**File # 1**

```
Row1 01205201207502102102…..

Row2 20101020100210201022…..

Row3 21050210210001120120…..
```

I want to do some statistics on that file and may be delete some columns or rows. So, using R, I want to add one space between each two characters in the second column to get something like this:

**File # 2**

```
Row1 0 1 2 0 5 2 0 1 2 0 7 5 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 2…..

Row2 2 0 1 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 2 0 1 0 2 2…..

Row3 2 1 0 0 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 1 2 0…..
```

And then, after I finish editing, remove the spaces between the characters in the second column, so the final format will be just like `File # 1`.

What is the best and faster way to do that?

Comment: Adding spaces doesn't seem related to "I want to do some statistics on that file and may be delete some columns or rows." Do we have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/203914) here?

Comment: If you know each column contains a single character, as your request implies, there's no need to separate them. You can index into each character string as they stand.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that. My goal is to see how many 5s and/or 7s in each row/column and then I would decide to remove or keep each the column or the row.

Comment: are you trying to make a matrix for the column 2 values so that each value is in a separate column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*updated* addressing the column count as well. ( From your comments)

Here is a solution using `tidyr` and `stringr`. However, this considers that your string is of equal length for the column2. The solution gives you both rowwise and columnwise count. This is done in very basic step by step manner, could be achieved the same with few lines of the code as well.

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

data<-data.frame( Column.1 = c("01205", "20705", "27057"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

count<-str_count(data$Column.1) # Get the length of the string in column 2
index<-1:count[1] # Generate an index based on the length

# Count the number of 5 and 7 in each string by row and add it as new column
data$Row.count_5 <- str_count(data$Column.1, "5")
data$Row.count_7 <- str_count(data$Column.1, "7")

new.data <- separate(data, Column.1, into = paste("V", 1:count[1], sep = ""), sep = index)
new.data$'NA' <- NULL
new.data

Column_count_5 <- apply(new.data[1:5],2,FUN=function(x) sum(x == 5))
Column_count_7 <- apply(new.data[1:5],2,FUN=function(x) sum(x == 7))
column_count <- as.data.frame(t(data.frame(Column_count_5,Column_count_7)))

library(plyr)
Final.df<- rbind.fill(new.data,column_count)
rownames(Final.df)<-c("Row1","Row2","Row3", "Column.count_5","Column.count_7")
Final.df
```

output

```
                V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 Row.count_5 Row.count_7
Row1            0  1  2  0  5           1           0
Row2            2  0  7  0  5           1           1
Row3            2  7  0  5  7           1           2
Column.count_5  0  0  0  1  2          NA          NA
Column.count_7  0  1  1  0  1          NA          NA
```

---

**Sample data**

```
data<-data.frame( Column.1 = c("01205", "20705", "27057"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```